# How to install latest version of RTAB-Map in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, kinect, ros

I use Ubuntu 16.04. I have downloaded RTAB-Map manually from [GitHub](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Installation#ubuntu), but when I check the version on my system, I only have 0.11.13. The latest version available is 0.14.3. How can I download or update to a newer version, preferably later than version 0.12?

Thank you!

Comment: download the latest source from https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/archive/0.14.0.tar.gz . Unzip it and-  
$ cd rtabmap/build  
$ cmake ..  
$ make -j4  
$ sudo make install

Comment: Before installing, I uninstall my old version.

Uninstall Ubuntu (or built from source)
-Remove the RTAB-Map's source directory.
-Remove RTAB-Map's working directory in "~/Documents/RTAB-Map".
-Remove RTAB-Map's configuration file in "~/.rtabmap/rtabmap.ini".

But after installing, there is no version change, and get error: "~/.rtabmap/rtabmap.ini doesn't exists.
How can I fix it?? @arunkjn

Comment: I have downloaded ros and rtabmap_ros also. Is that a problem?